# Can I "undo" buffering of a point layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, buffer

I have point layer, where each point is one tree, about 1300 trees in total. I made buffers around each tree, the buffer being the height of each tree in QGIS 2.0.1. 
My next step was to use Spatial Query to see if the buffers (the height of each tree) reached a road. The resault was that 60 buffers/trees reached the road.

I now want to show the location of each tree on a map, and I believe that the map would easier to read if it contained points instead of buffers.

Is there a way to go back and make points again from the layer with the selected buffers in QGIS?

Comment: Buffering a point layer will create a new polygon layer that contains the buffers. So for creating the map, you can simply hide the buffer polygon layer (or make it semi-transparent)

Comment: But I made a selection using the buffered layer. The original layer contains about 1300 points of which I selected about 60 using buffers and spatial query.

Comment: So save the selected points to a new point layer, and only display that in your map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a buffer **polygon** layer from a **point** layer, than you automatically should have the original point layer as well.

Alternatively just use the `Polygon Centroids` tool within the `Vector-> Geometry` menu.